# If I join the Kingdom of Swardia, will I lose my recruits?

Tags: mount-and-blade

In *Mount & Blade*, I've managed to recruit a small amount of troops from the Kingdom of Rhodoks.

I was recently given the option to join the Kingdom of Swardia as a mercenary. Unfortunately, Rhodoks and Swardia are currently undergoing a massive war, resulting in raids of several small villages in the Kingdom of Rhodoks (some of which played home to my recruits).

**Will my Rhodoksian recruits leave me if I pledge allegiance to their enemy?**

Comment: just be aware while they won't leave you, if swadia goes to war with the rhodoks and you participate in a bunch of campaigns against rhodoks, your rhodok units will lose a ton of morale and my desert

Comment: But the gain of morale in a combat usually outweighs that. It is only bad if you raid villages, which you should avoid at all anyway, if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Your army is loyal to you, if they have enough morale and you enough money to pay them. They don't care for whom they are fighting.

You can basically pick the best units from each nation, like Nords for Huscarls, Swadians for Cavallary and so on.

However, this does not apply to units stationed in a castle. If you own a castle that was given to you by your current king and you renounce your loyalty to him, then you loose that fief and all units inside.

As a sidenote, you should avoid recruiting units from taverns, since they are much more expensive. It can be a valid source of more men later on when you quickly need some good troops, but in the beginning it can ruin you.

Comment: Does that exclude the "hero" units which are often found in taverns?

Comment: Yes, they are called companions. You want them on your team to fill gaps in your skills. I often look out for a decent healer companion and someone that has engineer. Since you can't put hero characters into a castle you can't loose them. You only can send them away, or they leave your party on their own when you do bad things like raiding villages or if you don't do such things, depending on the companion :D.

Comment: The companions can come back later when they leave. I was happy to discover this since one of my better guys decided to leave, and later he came back :)